# Excel VBA - Sub not finishing after Call with Target

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make an a Worksheet that adapts depending on the different selections on the page. There are 3 cells wills drop down lists that will modify the page depending on the selected value. When I launch the sub directly in the Worksheet_SelectionChange it works without problems (as it's only one) but as I needed 3 I wanted to launch it depending on which cell you select. The problem I have now is that the selection works (test done with Showmsg) but everything that should happen after doesn't.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D25")) Is Nothing Then
            Call LineBlock_Change(Target)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

---------

Sub LineBlock_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'D25
    Select Case Target
    Case "Non Protected / Non Redundant"
        ' Affichage 1 Ligne
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = True
    Case Else
        ' Affichage 2 Ligne
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

The thing is that when I use the same code of the Sub in Worksheet_SelectionChange(with a limitation on the Cell that can be selected) It does work but while trying to lunch with a Sub it doesn't. I personnaly don't know if it can be followed up like that or if I need to rethink the way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Update : As I noticed that I might have some problems really explain what I can't do I will try an other approach.
I have this code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address <> "$D$25" Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target
     Case "Non Protected / Non Redundant"
        ' Affichage 1 Ligne
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = True
    Case Else
       ' Affichage 2 Ligne
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

It does exactly what I desire, when D25 has the string : "Non Protected / Non Redundant" it hides the Columns J:O. Now my problem is that D25 is not the only condition that I wish to have that will hide/unhide columns/rows. And such I'm trying to write a code that would launch a sub depending on which Cell is selected and what is inside of it.
Though when I try to write the code in a way that it would work as a sub it doesn't reacts the way I would like (hiding the columns).

Comment: Use `Case Else` rather than `Case Not "Non Protected / Non Redundant"`

Comment: Corrected, still, the follow up of the Hidden rows doesn't works.

Comment: Your code works as posted so there's something you aren't mentioning, or that's not the real code (which would explain all the typos).

Comment: That's the real code. I've tried it to launch it on a page or over a module and it doesn't works for me. What are the typos you are refering too if I may ask ?

Comment: All the ones mentioned in the comments. What **precisely** does *"doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: I've Updated my original Question in hope it may be a bit more clear.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what is happening? As I mentioned, your code works absolutely fine for me.

Comment: That makes me wonder, as for me it does nothing (the first code) I tried to go trough the code. It goes down to `Select Case Target` it seems to never go into the case "non protected" nor in the case else.
The second code directly from Worksheet_Change works totally fine for me.

Comment: It has to process at least one of those unless the code is being interrupted somehow. I assume you aren't seeing any error messages? Can you put a file somewhere (e.g. OneDrive or Dropbox) that I can look at?

Comment: @Rory - Here you go : dropbox.com/s/8kzrwb2z6yd14vi/Macro_Test.xlsm?dl=0 –

Comment: The code works but you have to select a different cell and then select D25 again after changing the value since it's a `SelectionChange` event and not a `Change` event.

Comment: Ohhh ! Awsome :D Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LineBlock_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'D25

    Stop '<-  see what happens
    Select Case Target

    Case "Non Protected / Non Redundant"
        ' Affichage 1 Ligne
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = True
    Case Else
        ' Affichage 2 Ligne
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = False        
    End Select

End Sub
```

The problem in `LineBlock` are the following:

- `Column` should be `Columns()`
- `Columns("J:O").EntireRow.Hidden = True` hides the whole worksheeet. That's great! But you probably need to remove the `EntireRow` part.

---

Edit:

Upon the update, reading that "D25 is not the only condition that I wish to have that will hide/unhide columns/rows" this is what you should do:

```
Select Case True

    Case Target = "Non Protected / Non Redundant"
        'some action
    Case Range("A1") = "something else"
        'some other action
    Case Else
        Columns("J:O").Hidden = False
End Select
```

Comment: @Ekounerio - have you tried changing `Bock` to `Block`?

Comment: Oh yes it's corrected directly after. But I'm sure it isn't that as the other subs don't work either. (Only gave the example with one.

Comment: @Ekounerio - this `Columns("J:O").EntireRow.Hidden = True` is probably the best code I have seen in the last 3 months! :) Thank you! :)

Comment: Well thank you :D And sadly doesn't makes any different if it's with EntireRow or not. The main problem I have is the feeling that the 'selection works but it doesn't goes further then that.

Comment: @write `Stop` before the `Select Case Target` and see what happens.

Comment: No visible diffrence

Comment: @Ekounerio - does it stop?

Comment: Well I get no inidication of something happening. I might try to launch with MsgBox instread of the hide code to see if it stops before or after

Comment: I've Updated my original Question in hope it may be a bit more clear

Comment: I see what you mean, but that's the way I wanted to avoid it. As I will probably have two other Cells with at least 4 conditions each. That's why I wanted to call a Sub instead of working directly from the Worksheet_Change.